# Python: Child Inheriting Parents Default Values If Not Specified

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, initialization, multiple-inheritance, super

fairly intermediate programmer but Python beginner here. I've been working on a game for a while and I restructured all of my classes yesterday. Where I was initially using only compositional data structure, I'm now using a mix of both. My issues come when I want to spawn the player. Here's the relevant code.

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        DeaultValues={'x':0, 'y':0, 'name':None, 'texture':None, 'blocks':False, 'ObjectID':None, 'Fighter':None, 'Corpse':None, 'Skill':None, 'ai':None}
        for key,value in DeaultValues.items(): 
            try: 
                vars(self)[key] = kwargs[key]
            except ValueError: 
                vars(self)[key] = value
            except KeyError:
                vars(self)[key] = value
        self.x = kwargs['x']
        self.y = kwargs['y']
        self.name=kwargs['name']
        self.blocks=kwargs['blocks']
        self.ObjectID=self.AttachID()
        self.texture = kwargs['texture']

        #This section binds an actors compenents to itself
        self.Corpse = kwargs['Corpse']
        if self.Corpse:
            self.Corpse.owner = self
        self.Skill=kwargs['Skill']
        if self.Skill:
            self.Skill.owner = self
        self.Fighter = kwargs['Fighter']
        if self.Fighter:
            self.Fighter.owner = self
        self.ai = kwargs['ai']
        if self.ai:
            self.ai.owner = self

class HighActor(Object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HighActor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Player(HighActor):
    def __init__(self, Level=1, Xp=0, PreviousLevel=0, PreviousLevelThreshold=100, LevelThreshold=500, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.LevelThreshold = LevelThreshold
        self.PreviousLevelThreshold=PreviousLevelThreshold
        self.PreviousLevel=PreviousLevel
        self.Level = Level
        self.Xp = Xp

def SpawnPlayer():
    global player
    FighterComponent = Fighter(MaxHp=100, Hp=100, IsHasted=[False, False], death_function=None)
    CorpseComponent = Corpse()
    SkillComponent = HighActorSkill()
    player=Player(name="player", x=None, y=None, texture="player.png", blocks=True, ObjectID=None, Fighter=FighterComponent, Corpse=CorpseComponent, Skill=SkillComponent, ai=None)
```

The above code works just fine, however its not really inheriting anything. To get the player object to not error I had to add to add all of the attributes of the base object class to the Player initialization. If I remove any of the values that are set to none in the player=Player() statement I get value errors or key errors. I tried to correct this by having a dict of default values that looped through all kwargs the init was given and if they had no value, set them to the default found. This worked until I got to any of the components. So in the case of not specifying ai=none, I got key errors. I would really love to have my code in such a format that if I do not specify a value for any of the base object class attributes the default values would be passed in, but if I do specify a value, that gets passed up to the base class. My ideal end result would be to have my player instancing look like this:

```
def SpawnPlayer():
    global player
    FighterComponent = Fighter(MaxHp=100, Hp=100, IsHasted=[False, False], death_function=None)
    CorpseComponent = Corpse()
    SkillComponent = HighActorSkill()
    player=Player(name="player", texture="player.png", blocks=True, Fighter=FighterComponent, Corpse=CorpseComponent, Skill=SkillComponent)
```

I have a suspicion that my inheritance isn't working 100% because I get errors if I leave out ObjectID even though that should be assigned since in the init of the bass class its set equal to getid(self). So I'm either having issues with my inheritance (I'm really struggling with Super), or the signatures of my objects, and I'm not quite sure what my problem is, and more importantly why. I'm not opposed to changing the codes signature dramatically, as I'm still writing the engine so nothing is reliant on this yet. What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class structure should be different. Each class should only have the attributes it needs, add new ones as you build up the inheritance, e.g.:

```
class Object(object):

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name


class HighActor(Object):

    def __init__(self, corpse=None, skill=None, **kwargs):
        super(HighActor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.corpse = corpse
        self.skill = skill


class Player(HighActor):

    def __init__(self, level=1, xp=0, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp
```

At each level you specify the attributes - all `Object`s should have `x`, `y` and `name`, all `HighActor`s should *also* have `corpse` and `skill`, etc. Now you can specify arguments to supply to any of the three levels of the hierarchy, or leave them out to get defaults:

```
player = Player(name="player one", skill=100, xp=12)
```

You may have things that don't fit into this inheritance scheme - it is OK to have more than one separate set of inheritance relationships in your model, don't force it!

---

This works because the `**kwargs` at the end of each `__init__` "mops up" any keyword arguments that method isn't expecting into a dictionary `kwargs`, and can then pass them all to the next level. When you do so, `super(...).__init__(**kwargs)`, this unpacks the dictionary back into keyword arguments, and any that aren't present will take the specified default value.

Comment: The majority of Actors in the game are built out of the base Object class. I omitted class methods here that make that apparent, but HighActor contains a lot of methods, and there is an additional Child for HighActor that has distinctions. The player class exists strictly because it is in fact a further specialization of the object class. All Actors die and use abilities, so all Objects need those comonents. My code is fully compliant with SoC. This does not even address the actual question.

Comment: All `Actor`s may be `Object`s, but not all `Object`s need to be `Actor`s. Why not add a `BaseActor` between `Object` and `HighActor`? Also, if you only show me a bit of the scheme I can only help you with a bit of it!

Comment: The thing that differentiates base actors from generic objects are the components that they become the owners of. Say I wanted an object in the game that was a geyser that on each turn emitted a poisonous cloud. I would initialize it as an Object with no Fighter or Corpse component but it would have a skill component to cast the poison cloud ability. The use of compositional structure here is to give me a large amount of flexibility with the objects I create allowing for a large amount of permutations of Objects and Actors without having an absurd number of classes to manage.

Comment: You will have to move the attributes to the appropriate part of the hierarchy, that's fine. Perhaps `Object` has `skill`s and `Actor` adds `corpse` and `Player` adds `fighter`; you are best placed to decide this. But the use of `**kwargs` and default arguments in my answer will get you past the problems you have.

Comment: This worked. An edit providing an explanation about Parent defaults vs Child specified values would be wonderful, as I've yet to come across a concrete explanation about how this works.

Comment: I've added another para, hope it helps.